# (Zeppelin + Livy) SparkUI.appUIAddress(), something must be wrong

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-zeppelin, livy

I'm trying to configure livy with Zeppelin following this docs:
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/livy.html

However when I run:

```
%livy.spark
sc.version
```

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No result can be extracted from 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.appUIAddress()', something must be wrong
```

I use Zeppelin 0.7.3, Spark 2.2.1, and Livy 0.4.0.
Spark running on YARN (hadoop 2.9.0). This is vanilla install, I don't use distribution like cloudera/HDP. All these software runs on one server.

I can run example org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi in spark-shell with --master yarn without any problem. So I confirm that spark is running well on YARN.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
yusata.

Comment: _"Spark running on YARN (hadoop 2.9.0)."_ Are you sure about that?! That's not possible (and am not talking about Hadoop 2.9.0 itself which is also unsupported).

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure. hdfs version & spark sc.version show 2.9.0 and 2.2.1 respectively. Besides, I can run simple calculation from spark-shell (--master yarn) using csv file in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

This problem results from a method depreciation in spark 2.2.The appUiAddress no longer exist in spark 2.2.

As you can see in this PR https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2231.
This issue is already solved.

Somehow you still encounter the problem. I think either downgrade Spark or use a newer version of Zeppelin could solve the problem.